# fix a bug in a Python logical task

Tags: python, algorithm, task

Task:
The store wants to find out when it makes the most money during its open time during the day. Analysts have theorized that there are two intervals that bring the maximum profit.

For analysis, the sums of all checks were unloaded, including returns to the sequence of real numbers.

As the first step of the analysis, it is necessary to find the maximum sum of two consecutive non-empty sequences of receipts; it is not necessary to search for the receipts themselves.

Example 1
Input
1 2 3 -1 1 2 3
Conclusion
12

Example 2
Input
1 2 1 2 1
Conclusion
7

```
checks = list(map(float, input().split()))
max_profit = float('-inf')
current_profit = 0
for check in checks:
    current_profit += check
    max_profit = max(max_profit, current_profit)
    if current_profit < 0:
        current_profit = 0
print(max_profit)
```

I got this code and I can't figure out the error. On the first test, it outputs 11, but it needs 12. The second test passes

Comment: This is a variation on the [maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). But instead of one subarray, you're looking for two. The semi-brute force solution is to split the array into two parts, and then run Kadane's algorithm on each part, trying every possible split point. You can optimize by choosing the split point more carefully. For example 2, the split point doesn't matter because all the numbers are positive. For the first example, the split point is either before or after the -1.

Answer (score 2):

The checks on `current_profit` reset the `current_profit` when they are negative. Instead of resetting the `current_profit`, set the `current_profit` to the `max_profit`.

```
if current_profit < max_profit:
        current_profit = max_profit
```

Also, I suggest not using `max_profit = float('-inf')`. Consider: `max_profit = 0`.

Comment: The examples in the question make the problem seem easier than it is. A better example would be `[1, 2, -5, 3, 4, 5, -2, 4, 1, -1, -2, 3, 2, 5, -6]`. The answer is 25 because the best *"two consecutive non-empty sequences"* are `[3, 4, 5, -2, 4, 1]` and `[2, 3, 5]` with sums 15 and 10 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you enter `-1` number after another numbers and the sum of the past numbers + -1, is bigger than 0.
So the first solution is changing the code as I write below:

```
checks = list(map(float, input().split()))
# max_profit = float('-inf')
max_profit = 0
current_profit = 0
for check in checks:
    if check < 0:
        check = 0
    current_profit += check
    max_profit = max(max_profit, current_profit)
    # if current_profit < 0:
    #     current_profit = 0
print(max_profit)
```

Also you can enter negative numbers first and then enter other numbers in your code!